# Cheerio: How to select by data tag

Tags: cheerio

Let's say I have an element like this:

```
<div data-testid="counter">Count: 3</div>
```

How can I select that element by querying for the `"counter"` `data-testid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all just css so if you need reference look at the w3c specs:

```
$('[data-testid="counter"]')
```